# Trace of a nonzero symmetric positive semi-definte matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

We have an $(n \times n)$ real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix A such that $A\neq 0$. Does this imply that $tr(A)>0$?

---

**Comments**: It follows from the p.s.d of the matrix that all eigenvalues, $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$, are non-negative: Hence, $tr(A)=\sum_i^{n}\lambda_i\geq 0$.
However I don't see how the fact that $A$ is symmetric and $A\neq 0$ helps us to show that $tr(A)\neq 0$

Comment: Hello :) The matrix with all entries equal to zero is a real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.

Comment: Hi @Jochen. Yes indeed, matrix with all entries equal to zeros is  a  real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. However, I am interested in "non-zero" matrices. Any ideas how to handle this problem

Comment: Hello! If $\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$ then all eigenvalues are $0$, which contradicts $A\neq 0$!

Comment: @ChongxuRen In general if all eigenvalues values are $0$ this does not unfortunately imply that the matrix is zero. For instance,
$\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ has all eigenvalues zero

Comment: Yes! Symmetric matrix is always diagonalizable but the general case is not true.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @ChongxuRen, I found a correct answer.

From p.s.d of matrix $A$ we have that $tr(A)\geq 0$, Hence it remains to show that $tr(A)\neq 0$.

Lets prove it from contradiction.
Lets $tr(A)=0$, this implies that all eigenvalues are zero (since $0\leq tr(A)$). In general, if all eigenvalues are zero it is not necessary that the matrix is zero. However, if matrix $A$ is a real and symmetric than we have $A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i'$, where $\{\lambda_i\}$ are eigenvectors and $\{v_i\}$ is associated orthonormal eigenvectors. Hence, for real symmetric matrix if all eigenvalues are zero than $A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i'=0$ and this contradicts initial condition $A\neq 0$.

Comment: Can you explain why it holds that $A = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i v_i v_i'$?