# Lower bound on quadratic form with positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I came accross the following lower bound and I am looking for a proof that uses only basic properties or well-established results of linear algebra (or other domains of math).

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix and $D = \text{diag}\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_d\}$ the diagonal matrix of the $d$ eigenvalues of $M$. For any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ it should hold that $$x'Mx \geq x'Dx$$

Can somebody help with proving this?

Comment: Symmetric positive definite matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable so $M = QDQ^T$ with $Q^TQ = QQ^T = I$ and so your question is equivalent to showing:
$$x'(QDQ^T - D)x\geq 0$$
or equivalently $M-D$ is positive semidefinite. I am not sure if this is true in general

Comment: $$ M = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
5 & -4 \\ 
-4 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$   and $$ x = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Your definition of $D$ is ambiguous because you don't give the order in which you rank the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the condition under the form :

$$\forall x, \ x^T(M-D)x \ge 0,$$

a consequence is that $M-D$ is a (symmetric) semi-definite positive matrix, which is traceless ($\operatorname{trace}(M-D)=\operatorname{trace}(M)-\operatorname{trace}(D) = 0$).

This is impossible for a non-zero matrix, as established [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4211914/305862).

The only possible case is therefore when $M-D=0 \ \iff \ M=D$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have that $M$ is symmetric and positive definite, and $-D$ is diagonal and negative definite. Can you explain how to infer that the sum $M - D$ is semi-positive definite?

Comment: Just because a matrix $A$ is semi-positive definite iff $\forall x, x^T\!\!Ax \ge 0$...

Comment: ok, this one was clear :-)

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is true iff $M=D.$ The proof will be performed by induction on $d.$
WLOG we may assume that $\lambda_1$ is the greatest eigenvalue. Then $M\le \lambda_1I.$
By assumption
$e_1'Me_1\ge \lambda_1.$ Thus $e_1'(M-\lambda_1I)e_1\ge 0.$ As $\lambda_1I-M$ is positive definite, we get $(M-\lambda I) e_1=0,$ i.e. $Me_1=\lambda_1e_1.$  As $M$ is positive definite the subspace $e_1^\perp$ is invariant for $M,$ and clearly for $D.$ Now we may restrict to $e_1^\perp$ and apply the induction hypothesis to show that $M$ restricted to $e_1^\perp$ is diagonal. Thus $M$ is diagonal.